# Setting Opacity on parent <Grid /> makes children indepedently transparent

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a list of items, and when an item becomes "complete", it's opacity is set to 0.4 to fade it away. Also when an item is completed, the icon gets an orange-yellow completion overlay.

[image].

The markup for this is something similar to

```
<Grid Opacity="{x:Bind IsCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNumberConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.4|1}">
    [...]

    <Canvas>
        <Image />

        <Rectangle
            Visibility="{x:Bind IsCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
            Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0"
            Width="48"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Opacity="1"
            Height="48" Stroke="#ffC19954" />

        <Polygon
            Visibility="{x:Bind IsCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
            Opacity="1"
            Canvas.Top="23" Canvas.Left="23" Points="0,25 25,25, 25,0" Fill="#ffC19954" />
    </Canvas>

    [...]
</Grid>
```

The problem I'm having is that it appears the opacity is applied individually to each descendant, so the orange completion triangle appears semi-tranparent on top of the icon, and you can see the icon underneath. You can also see this where the triangle overlaps the border.

Instead, the desired behaviour is that the triangle should be completely opaque and the grid *as a whole* should be semi-transparent, as it behaves in CSS:

> opacity applies to the element as a whole, including its contents, even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, the element and its children all have the same opacity relative to the element's background, even if they have different opacities relative to one another.

It should look like

[image]

(note how the white icon is not visible through the orange triangle)

Is there a way to change how opacity is composited and rendered to achieve this?  Very soon the app's background will be slightly transparent, so I need a solution that will work with that as well.

Comment: Maybe you could try to get the RGB about the color of Polygon which has the 0.4 transparency from the second image, then apply the new RGB to the color of Polygon. In this case, overlay Polygon on your Grid and keep Opacity at 1.

Comment: Is that going to work if the application's background is semi-transparent?

Comment: How did you set the application's background to semi-transparent? Using acrylic?  It won't affect the Opacity of Polygon, you could try it to see if it can achieve the effect you want.

Comment: I thought about it, but moving that part of the icon outside of the grid and setting a different solid colour was just too much hassle for what I get from it - just not worth it. Was hoping there was some different compositing/opactiy-cascade mode I could opt into

Comment: You can check the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.opacity?view=winrt-19041#remarks) part of Opacity property, it mentions if an object that has Opacity=0.5 is contained in a Canvas that is also Opacity=0.5, the effective Opacity value for rendering is 0.25. So even if you set the Opacity of Polygon as 1, the effective Opacity value for rendering is still equal to the Opacity of Grid. Or you can set the Opacity of each child Element which you want semi-transparent using Binding instead of directly set the Opacity of parent.

Answer (score -1):

You can get around this by simply doing the inverse.

Put a mask grid, above the item, set a solid color to the grid, set it to `0` opacity, and simply increase its opacity when you want the content behind to fade.

```
<Grid Name="BaseGrid">
<Canvas>
        <Image />
    [...]
</Canvas>

<Grid Name="MaskGrid" Background="Gainsboro" Opacity="0.2"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Interesting and novel solution, but I don't think this will work that well because if my app's background is transparent (which it is about to be), then I'm thinking it will be trickier to set the right opacity on that overlay...

Comment: if you are using acrylic, you can set the background of the mask grid to be acrylic too.

Comment: As I demonstrate in this mockup https://i.imgur.com/2965R8F.png, applying a colored overlay "mask" to "fade out" my content does not work when the app's background is transparent because the colour from the mask will added onto the semi-transparent app background